# How to get multiple wildcard % in the middle of a DataView RowFilter same as sql

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this row filter text:

```
"[add1] = '" + startAddress+ "%" + middle+ "%" + end +"'"
```

which fails, but if I put the `%` at the beginning or end it's OK.

Is there any way to achieve the same result (i.e. "any" string in the middle of the names)?

Full statement is:

```
dv = new DataView(MyDataTable, "[add1] = '" + startAddress+ "%" + middle+ "%" + end + + "'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Here i want filteration like `"%something%someone%"` How can i achieve this? Even using linq is also ok with me